# How to get the assembly name hosting a control at design-time

Tags: c#, user-interface

How do I get the name of the assembly hosting a control at design time.

What I need to do is have access to this name so that I can do certain things depending on which assembly the control was used in. This control is internal and is not intended for public use before someone rags on me.

EDIT:
This works

```
if (this.ParentForm != null)
    hostingAssembly = this.ParentForm.GetType().Assembly.GetName().FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
yourControlInstance.GetType().Assembly.GetName();
```

This will give you [AssemblyName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you can get its `Name`, `FullName` and some other parameters.

Comment: That gives me the assembly of the control. I'm calling this from within the control itself. Just to clarify, I need the assembly the control is used / hosted in at design time.

Comment: This works....you got me on the right track. if (this.ParentForm != null)
                    hostingAssembly = this.ParentForm.GetType().Assembly.GetName().FullName;